# Slick slider showing only text

Tags: javascript, slick.js

When I try to implement this Slick slider I get only a list of the numbers like in the image:
https://codepen.io/AntFArm/pen/JNEgJE

html code:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="slider slider-for">
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider slider-nav">
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="action">
    <a href="#" data-slide="3">go to slide 3</a>
    <a href="#" data-slide="4">go to slide 4</a>
    <a href="#" data-slide="5">go to slide 5</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

js code:

```
 $('.slider-for').slick({
   slidesToShow: 1,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   arrows: false,
   fade: true,
   asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
 });
 $('.slider-nav').slick({
   slidesToShow: 3,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   asNavFor: '.slider-for',
   dots: true,
   focusOnSelect: true
 });

 $('a[data-slide]').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var slideno = $(this).data('slide');
   $('.slider-nav').slick('slickGoTo', slideno - 1);
 });
```

I get this:

[image]

I have the exact same code as on the codepen.io site..
Also I don't have any errors.
What am I doing wrong? THanks in advance.

My script includes:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/slick/slick.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.slider-for').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        fade: true,
        asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
    });
    $('.slider-nav').slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        asNavFor: '.slider-for',
        dots: true,
        focusOnSelect: true
    });

    $('a[data-slide]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var slideno = $(this).data('slide');
        $('.slider-nav').slick('slickGoTo', slideno - 1);
    });
</script>
```

I load the necessary files in head:

[image]

Comment: Did you also include the js dependencies (jQuery, slick-carousel.js) on your page? Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: i added them to my code above

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is run as it is seen.  Seeing as your code doesn't work I have to assume that you are adding your script in the `<head>` or at least before where you define `<div class="main">`.  The rendering engine has not yet rendered your relevant slider elements so it cannot find them and does... nothing.

Either wrap your script in an onload (or a `$(function() {/* your code here */})`) or put your script at the bottom of your page

Comment: $.getScript("/js/jquery-ui.min.js", function(){
        alert("Script loaded and executed.");
    });

I do this but doesn't help..

Comment: I don't see how what you wrote has anything to do with what I said?

Comment: I load the necesary files in my head section; see original question thx!

Comment: Reread my answer... I'm telling you that when your script runs in <head> (as you confirmed) the <div class="main"> element doesn't exist yet so it doesn't find the elements and doesn't do anything.  You either have to make the contents of your script run onload or move the script to the bottom of your <body>

Answer (score 0):

Seems like slick default styles are not applied double check you have them and the path to them is correct.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/slick/slick.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your codepen, slick is not loaded so you get the default DOM display of your divs (one under each other). There must be something wrong with your loading of the scripts.